# CLOUD FUNCTION - How to write a reference document and fix NaN

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Thank you for your assistance in advance.

I am trying to pull prices from firestore and when a document is updated. Then it needs to go through a number of if statements to determine the prices then create a new document called payments, but payments documents need to have the booking referenced and looped to see if there is already a document created, if there is a document, then it needs to update the document.

The number values are given as NaN in the database and I cannot figure out why.

Please see the code below:

```js
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();


exports.paymentCalcAmount = functions.firestore
  .document(`{bookings}/{id}`)
  .onUpdate((snapshots, context) => {
    const payments = admin.firestore().collection("payments");
    const collection = admin.firestore().collection("bookings");
    const id = context.params.id;
    let startDate;
    let endDate;
    let cabinetVal = 0;
    let laundry = 0;
    let fridge = 0;
    let oven = 0;
    let window = 0;
    let wall = 0;
    let cleaningPrice: number;
    let discount: number;
    let stay_Over: number;
    let visiting: number;
    let houspitality_cut: number = 0;
    let service_provider_cut: number = 0;
    let TOTALHRS: number = 0;
    let TOTALPRICE: number = 0;
    let discountedPrice: number = 0;
    db.collection("prices")
      .doc("price")
      .get()
      .then(
        (snapshot: {
          data: {
            cleaning: number;
            discount: number;
            stay_over: number;
            visiting: number;
          };
        }) => {
          cleaningPrice = snapshot.data.cleaning;
          discount = 100 - snapshot.data.discount;
          stay_Over = snapshot.data.stay_over;
          visiting = snapshot.data.visiting;
        }
      );
    db.collection('bookings')
      .doc('{id}')
      .get()
      .then(
        (snap: {
          data: {
            isCleaning: boolean;
            isLaundry: boolean;
            isFridge: boolean;
            isOven: boolean;
            isCabinet: boolean;
            isWindow: boolean;
            isWall: boolean;
            stayOver: boolean;
            startDate: any;
            endDate: any;
          };
        }) => {
          if (snap.data.isCleaning === true) {
            if (snap.data.isCabinet === true) {
              cabinetVal = 1;
            }
            if (snap.data.isLaundry === true) {
              laundry = 1.5;
            }
            if (snap.data.isFridge === true) {
              fridge = 0.5;
            }
            if (snap.data.isOven === true) {
              oven = 0.5;
            }
            if (snap.data.isWindow === true) {
              window = 1;
            }
            if (snap.data.isWall === true) {
              wall = 1;
            }
            TOTALHRS = cabinetVal + laundry + fridge + oven + window + wall;
            TOTALPRICE = TOTALHRS * cleaningPrice;
            houspitality_cut = (TOTALPRICE / 100) * 27;
            service_provider_cut = TOTALPRICE - houspitality_cut;

            if (discount === 100) {
              discountedPrice = (TOTALPRICE / 100) * discount;
              TOTALPRICE = discountedPrice;
              houspitality_cut = (TOTALPRICE / 100) * 27;
              service_provider_cut = TOTALPRICE - houspitality_cut;
            }
          } else {
            if (snap.data.stayOver === true) {
              startDate = snap.data.startDate;
              endDate = snap.data.endDate;
              const days = Math.round((startDate-endDate)/(1000*60*60*24));

              TOTALPRICE = stay_Over * days;
              houspitality_cut = (TOTALPRICE / 100) * 27;
              service_provider_cut = TOTALPRICE - houspitality_cut;
            } else {
              startDate = snap.data.startDate;
              endDate = snap.data.endDate;
              const difference_in_time = endDate - startDate;
              const difference_in_days = difference_in_time / (1000 * 3600 * 24);

              TOTALPRICE = visiting * difference_in_days;
              houspitality_cut = (TOTALPRICE / 100) * 27;
              service_provider_cut = TOTALPRICE - houspitality_cut;
            }
          }
          db.collection("payments")
            .doc()
            .get()
            .then((Snapshot: { docs: any[] }) => {
              Snapshot.docs.forEach((docs) => {
                if (
                  docs.data.booking_ref === `${collection}${id}`
                ) {
                  return payments.update({
                    payment_total: TOTALPRICE,
                    houspitality_cut: houspitality_cut,
                    service_provider_cut: service_provider_cut,
                    total_hours: TOTALHRS,
                  });
                } else {
                  return payments.add({
                    booking_ref: collection,id,
                    payment_total: TOTALPRICE,
                    houspitality_cut: houspitality_cut,
                    service_provider_cut: service_provider_cut,
                    total_hours: TOTALHRS,
                  });
                }
              });
            });
        }
      );
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current code, you are overriding types that you shouldn't be and using forbidden types like `any` improperly. TypeScript is there to handle the types for you and the Firebase SDK is set up to support TypeScript out of the box.

Starting off, you have configured your function to respond to any top level collection (it would respond to `/users/someId`, `/posts/someId`, and so on - including `/payments/someId`!):

```
functions.firestore.document(`{bookings}/{id}`)
```

should be:

```
functions.firestore.document(`bookings/{id}`)
```

Next, you pass in your ID from `context` incorrectly:

```
db.collection('bookings').doc('{id}')
```

should be one of:

```
db.collection('bookings').doc(id)
db.collection('bookings').doc(context.params.id)
snapshots.after.ref
```

Because this Cloud Function is passed in the data related to this event, you don't need to fetch its data again:

```
const bookingSnapshot = await db.collection('bookings').doc(id).get()
```

can be replaced with just

```
const bookingSnapshot = snapshots.after;
```

Regarding overriding the types, these lines:

```
docRef
  .get()
  .then(
    (snap: {
      data: {
        isCleaning: boolean;
        isLaundry: boolean;
        isFridge: boolean;
        isOven: boolean;
        isCabinet: boolean;
        isWindow: boolean;
        isWall: boolean;
        stayOver: boolean;
        startDate: any;
        endDate: any;
      };
    }) => {
```

should just be:

```
docRef
  .get()
  .then((snap) => { // snap is already a DataSnapshot<DocumentData>
```

The `snap` object is not a `{ data: Record<string, any> }` but a `DataSnapshot<DocumentData>` (which looks closer to a `{ data: () => Record<string, any> }` - note that this is a method, not a property). By overriding this type, the linter, which would normally be throwing errors, doesn't know any better.

With your current overrides, TypeScript won't throw errors at you saying that `snap.data.isCleaning` is **always** `undefined`, `snap.data.isLaundry` is **always** `undefined`, and so on.

If you want to define the shape of the data at this reference, use:

```
docRef
  .withConverter(myDataConverter) // see https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/global.html#FirestoreDataConverter
  .get()
  .then((snap) => {
```

or

```js
docRef
  .get()
  .then((snap: admin.firestore.DataSnapshot<{
    isCleaning: boolean;
    isLaundry: boolean;
    isFridge: boolean;
    isOven: boolean;
    isCabinet: boolean;
    isWindow: boolean;
    isWall: boolean;
    stayOver: boolean;
    startDate?: number; // <-- don't use any here
    endDate?: number; // <-- don't use any here
  }>) => {
```

Because you also overrode the types for your collection query, you also don't get the errors for these lines:

```
db.collection("payments")
  .doc()
  .get()
  .then((snapshot: { docs: any[] }) => {
```

which should be (to get all documents in the `/payments` collection):

```
db.collection("payments") // note: doc() was removed
  .get()
  .then((querySnapshot) => { // querySnapshot is already a QuerySnapshot<DocumentData>
```

Lastly, you are using variables that are defined outside of your Promise chains. Because the function already has the data for the current booking, the code in its Promise chain is executed before the function retrieves the data for `cleaningPrice`, `discount` and so on. This means that all your calculations end up doing stuff like `10 * undefined` which results in `NaN`. You should make sure that you have all of the data you need prior to performing the calculation. You can achieve this using the [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) methods like `Promise.all`, or switch to `async`/`await` syntax. Read up on this [here](https://web.dev/promises/).

As an **example** how to rewrite your function to correct these problems (needs error handling!):

```
exports.paymentCalcAmount = functions.firestore
  .document(`bookings/{id}`)
  .onUpdate(async (change, context) => {
    const db = admin.firestore();
    
    const bookingId = context.params.id;
    const bookingData = change.after.data() as {
      isCleaning: boolean;
      isLaundry: boolean;
      isFridge: boolean;
      isOven: boolean;
      isCabinet: boolean;
      isWindow: boolean;
      isWall: boolean;
      stayOver: boolean;
      startDate?: number;
      endDate?: number;
    };
    const bookingPaymentRef = db
      .collection("payments")
      .doc(bookingId);
    
    const pricingData = await db
      .collection("prices")
      .doc("price")
      .get()
      .then(snap => snap.data());
    
    if (bookingData.isCleaning) {
      const cleaningHourlyRate = pricingData.cleaning;
      const cleaningRateMultiplier = (100 - (pricingData.discount || 0)) / 100;
      let total_hours = 0;
      
      if (bookingData.isCabinet) total_hours += 1;
      if (bookingData.isLaundry) total_hours += 1.5;
      if (bookingData.isFridge)  total_hours += 0.5;
      if (bookingData.isOven)    total_hours += 0.5;
      if (bookingData.isWindow)  total_hours += 1;
      if (bookingData.isWall)    total_hours += 1;
      
      const payment_total = cleaningHourlyRate * total_hours * cleaningRateMultiplier;
      const houspitality_cut = payment_total * 0.27;
      const service_provider_cut = payment_total - houspitality_cut;
      
      await bookingPaymentRef
        .set({
          payment_total,
          houspitality_cut,
          service_provider_cut,
          total_hours
        }, { merge: true });
      
    } else {
      const stayOverDailyRate = pricingData.stayOver;
      const visitingDailyRate = pricingData.visiting;
      const deltaTime = bookingData.endDate - bookingData.startDate;
      const deltaTimeInDays = deltaTime/(1000*60*60*24);
      
      const payment_total = bookingData.stayOver
        ? stayOverDailyRate * Math.round(deltaTimeInDays)
        : visitingDailyRate * deltaTimeInDays;
        
      const houspitality_cut = payment_total * 0.27;
      const service_provider_cut = payment_total - houspitality_cut;
      
      await bookingPaymentRef
        .set({
          payment_total,
          houspitality_cut,
          service_provider_cut,
          total_hours: 0,
        }, { merge: true });
    }
    
    console.log(`Successfully updated booking #${id}`);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

If those value had been wrongfully stored as string (notice the double-quotes around the value), you'll first have to parse to number, in order to compute them. I mean, you'd expect the calculation to be: `1 + 1 = 2`, but what may instead happen is: `"1" + "1" = "11"` (where the result is `NaN`).

Comment: The value on the database is a Number. So that's why I am confused. But I am also struggling to figure out how to write the document reference as a document reference. Right now it is as a string.
How would I write it to make it a reference?

Comment: In this case, the `NaN` values come from arithmetic involving `undefined` caused by a race condition where `cleaningPrice`, `discount` and so on haven't had their values retrieved before the calculations take place.